# How running a single test through testName in the command Line?

Tags: java, testng

```
@Test(testName="van")
public class Mytest{

//testcase}
```

I need to use testName "van" to run case from Testng

Comment: How do you run your tests ? Using Maven? Gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

Using maven do this:

```
mvn test -Dtest=Mytest#testFunctionName
```